# CSS flex direction column and column span

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve the following with `flex-direction: column`:

```
.page
---------------------
| H1                |
|---------|---------|
|  DIV 1  |  DIV 3  |
|         |---------|
|---------|  DIV 4  |
|  DIV 2  |         |
|         |         |
---------------------
```

It's important to note, that I want the markup to stay the same, so right now it looks like this:

```
<div class="page">
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

this is what I tried, but the `h1` isn't really spanning, but occupying the whole column instead:

```
.page {
  width: 210mm;
  height: 297mm;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 12pt;
  background: #FFF;

  margin: 5mm;
  padding: 12mm;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.page > * {
}

h1 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Use `grid` on this not `flex`. In addition i see that you are setting A4 printing dimensions in your page, so this is probably a printing template (e.g. for an invoice). Better transform that to pixels, you will find several pages  online converting `mm` to `px` based on `dpi`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **CSS** [`grid`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/), check the example snippet.

```css
.page {
  width: 100% /*2480px = 210mm @ 300dpi*/;
  height: 100% /*3508px = 297mm @ 300dpi*/;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: .875rem;
  background: #FFF;
  display: grid;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 48.5%);
  grid-template-rows:  15% 20% 20% 20% 20%;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  grid-column-gap: 1%;
  grid-row-gap: 1%;
  align-self: stretch;
}
h1 {
 font-size: 1rem;
 grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3;
 background-color: #ccc;
 width:100%;
 height: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 display: table;
}
div {
  display: table;
  align-self: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: table
}

div span, h1 span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.div1 {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 4 / 2;
  background-color: #cfcfcf;
}
.div2 {
  grid-area: 4 / 1 / 6 / 2;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.div3 {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
}
.div4 {
  grid-area: 3 / 2 / 6 / 3;
  background-color: #a3a3a3;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <h1><span>H1</span></h1>
  <div class="div1"><span>DIV 1</span></div>
  <div class="div2"><span>DIV 2</span></div>
  <div class="div3"><span>DIV 3</span></div>
  <div class="div4"><span>DIV 4</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution works only, if you know the amount of rows the page is going to have. Also, it assumes that all `divs` share the same height ratio. I.e. a `p` would either be overflowing or have a leftover whitespace before the next element. You also have to assign the `grid-area`, which doesn't make this a dynamic solution.

Comment: @Johannes yes `grid` is not dynamic, meaning that you have to pre-calculate every element's thesis and assign your grid-areas accordingly. But as you saw in the question's `CSS` width and height are set to A4, so my answer assumes in a way that. For example an invoice usually has A4 size and has static areas so using `grid` is great for that case.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

HTML

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="row">
      <div>DIV 1 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row splitRow">
    <div class="row">
      <div>DIV 2 </div>
      <div>DIV 3 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>DIV 4 </div>
      <div>DIV 5 </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.row{
  display:flex;
}
.splitRow{
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
div{
  border:1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: *"It's important to note, that I want the markup to stay the same..."*

Comment: I tried a few combinations, and `display: flex` doesn't seem to work in this use case without changing the markup. Changing it works, but `column-count` seems to be an easier solution that doesn't require changing the markup.